# Tomcat 8.5.34 accepted ciphers/protocols when using OpenSSLImplementation

Tags: ssl, tomcat, tomcat7, protocols, server.xml

I'm using tomcat version 8.5.34 and is put behind a NGINX. Because i want to reuse the connection (prevent repeating handshakes) i'm investigating the ussage of OpenSSLImplementation.
My server.xml looks like:

```
    <Connector SSLEnabled="true"
               port="8443"
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"

                sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation"
               executor="tomcatThreadPool" >

      <SSLHostConfig>
        sslProtocols = "TLSv1.2"
        protocols = "TLSv1.2"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
        ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
        SSLVerifyClient="optional"/>
      <Certificate
              certificateKeyFile="/Users/vdBerg/Developer/apache/<mydomain>.key"
              certificateFile="/Users/vdBerg/Developer/apache/<mydomain>.crt"
              type="RSA" />
      </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

As you can see in the configuration i tried several options to only support TLSv1.2.
But somehow these settings aren't picked up by tomcat.

When i run sslscan against my host:port, i still see it supports other protocols:

```
sslscan <mydomain>:8443

Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Preferred TLSv1.1  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.1  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Preferred TLSv1.0  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve P-256 DHE 256
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
Accepted  TLSv1.0  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
```

Who can tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Ok it's working now, i just had the wrong structure:
Instead of

```
<SSLHostConfig>
        sslProtocols = "TLSv1.2"
        protocols = "TLSv1.2"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
        ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"
        SSLVerifyClient="optional"/>
      <Certificate
              certificateKeyFile="/Users/vdBerg/Developer/apache/<mydomain>.key"
              certificateFile="/Users/vdBerg/Developer/apache/<mydomain>.crt"
              type="RSA" />
      </SSLHostConfig>
```

I had to use:

```
      <SSLHostConfig
              protocols = "+SSLv2Hello+TLSv1.2-TLSv1-TLSv1.1"
      >
        <Certificate
                certificateKeyFile="/Users/vdBerg/Developer/apache/mydomain.key"
                certificateFile="/Users/vdBerg/Developer/apache/mydomain.crt"
                type="RSA" />
      </SSLHostConfig>
```

Comment: *"...  and is put behind a NGINX"* - are you sure that you are not testing the nginx configuration here?

Comment: You can try to explicitly exclude version 1.0 and 1.1: `sslProtocols = "TLSv1.2-TLSv1-TLSv1.1"`

Comment: In my local environment i'm not using a nginx (that's the server setup).
I also tried you suggestion Romeo, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please do not mix APR and NIO connector.(read carefull http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html ). I can't see "honorCipherOrder" in your config and part on catalina.out log here.